# Fullcalendar Scheduler Plugin timeline view change resource height dynamically

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar scheduler pulgin for timeline view, we need change resource height and corresponding row height should be dynamically, based on given input of the resources.For xxample here we have used two resources.

For now i have no idea to do this one. Any advice would be greatfully recieved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "based on give input of the resources"...can you be clearer what you mean by this exactly?

Comment: @ADyson ,i have updated my question.number of resources used.

Comment: Ok thanks. AFAIK there is no setting for that, unfortunately. What you can do, if it's useful, is resize the calendar instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing

Comment: @ADyson do u have any custmize allDaySlot, into separte into two rows am/pm ??

Comment: for that you'd have to write a completely custom view, it's not really a road you want to go down if you can possibly help it.